# How do you open a file in a different solution by clicking on a type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

One of the projects I work on is distributed over different solutions. So unfortunately when I click 'Go To Definition' for a type in a file that is in a different project it opens the meta data only. Given that the project is on my machine and has all the pdbs is there no way for visual studio to just open the file just like it does when you step into it using the debugger?

Comment: Just attach the solution to the project.

Comment: You are expecting Visual Studio to guess where the source code for the assembly is stored.  Given that it doesn't have great odds to guess correctly, or that it is even available at all, it implements a way that always works.  Simply add the project to the solution.  Removing it later is simple too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you buying Resharper 6 (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it adds a code decompiler and you can decompile almost any type that you are using, even Microsoft libraries.

But you can't edit it.

Comment: ILSPY can be an alternative :)

Comment: This isnt what I was asking I just want to know about the source code being opened with a command in visual studio just like the happens when you step into it. Thanks for respondng though...

Answer (score 0):

Other way you can do is disassemble the assemby you have to see your C# code, just use ILSPY unless your assembly is not obfuscated.

Comment: This isnt what I was asking I just want to know about the source code being opened with a command in visual studio just like the happens when you step into it. Thanks for respondng though...

Comment: Do note i said "Other way" because i already noted others replied saying its not possible. Hence i suggest simpler way to see code via disassembler.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to:

1. Remove old reference.
2. Add 'Project Reference'.

Then after your click 'Go To Definition' VS will redirect you to the code you are looking for.

Comment: This is used by a team of developers so I cant really add the project. Cant believe there isnt a way to set visual studio up to open the file. It does it in Debug mode....